# Python (NumPy): Collections can only map rank 1 arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm running into the following error and I'm not sure why...

```
>>> x = np.matrix([[1,2,3,4]])
>>> x
matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> pcolor(x)
<matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection object at 0x108bb1810>
>>> show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1006, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 755, in draw
    return Collection.draw(self, renderer)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 244, in draw
    self.update_scalarmappable()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 609, in update_scalarmappable
    raise ValueError('Collections can only map rank 1 arrays')
ValueError: Collections can only map rank 1 arrays
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `x` is a rank two array -- it has two dimensions. Observe the doubled braces, and then look at the `shape` attribute of the matrix; you'll see that it has two dimensions, one of which is of size 1. All matrices in `numpy` are 2-dimensional.

Comment: How can I plot a vector using pcolor if it does not accept lists or matrices?

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm trying to plot the vector [1,2,3,4].

Comment: @nick_name: How does that relate to `pcolor`?  Can you read [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor) for pcolor and look at [the example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html) and explain what your desired output is from that vector?

Comment: @BrenBarn I want a 1D binned color plot with normalized colors. See: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_small.html.

Comment: Did you try just using a regular numpy array instead of a matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just cast your matrix to a ndarray:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import pcolor, show
x = np.matrix([[1,2,3,4]])
pcolor(np.array(x))
show()
```

Are you sure that you need a matrix in the first place ? A ndarray is far easier to use and far more common.